# How to use angular js to refresh a table after hit submit button

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write a app using python Flask and angular JS.

In my index.html, I have following code

```
<div ng=controller="QueryController as queryController">
<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="queryController.queryCode"/>
<input type="submit" value="Query"/>
</form>

<table>
<tr ng-repeat="row in queryController.results">
    <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

When index.html is loaded, the table will be empty, after people inputed query text in text field, I want to reload table to show query result.
The query result is from an http request.

How should I let javascript to reload the form after getting query result.

Comment: Do you want to send the data to a backend service and get the result of the  action or get the data that you sent to the service and put in the table?

Answer (score 2):

Use the **ng-submit** directive on your form and make it trigger a function that simply:

1. executes the query in `queryController.queryCode`
2. retrieves the result and stores it in `queryController.results`

The binding you've done in your html between that result variable and your table content is sufficient for your page to be updated as soon as `queryController.results` changes, without you doing anything else.

---

Here's an example of what your **html** code could look like:

```
<div ng=controller="QueryController as queryController">
    <form ng-submit="queryController.executeQuery()">   <!-- used ngSubmit here -->
        <input type="text" ng-model="queryController.queryCode"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Query"/>
    </form>

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in queryController.results">
            <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

... and the additional code in your controller:

```
...
queryController.executeQuery = function() {
    // pseudo-code that executes your query and gives you back a promise
    var promise = database.query(queryController.queryCode);
    promise.then(function (resultSet) {
        queryController.results = resultSet;
    });
};
...
```

---

***EDIT:***

Since you mentioned that you execute your query *via* an **http** request, [here is a link to the AngularJS way](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) to do so.

***TL;DR:***

Assuming you're using the **http POST** method to execute your query:

```
$http.post(/*your database server URL*/, JSON.stringify(queryController.queryCode))
    .success(function(data) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available
        queryController.results = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Please note that you'll also need to serialise/deserialise your data to transfer it through **http**. I did so in my example, featuring a simple way to parse and write using the JSON format.

Comment: In your starting code `<div ng=controller="QueryController as queryController">`. Are you sure? It's not `ng-controller` instead your have  written `ng=controller`? Is it a mistake or this type of method is available in angularjs?

Comment: Oops, it's indeed just a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

Do the form submit in an `ng-submit`, like:

```
<form ng-submit="queryController.submit()">
```

And in your controller:

```
queryController.submit = function() {
    $http
       .post(...) // the form submit action
       .then(function() { // form submitted successfully, update your table
           $http
              .get(...)
              .then(function(result) {
                 queryController.results = result;
              });
       });
}
```